# Form not reading the select attribute when added option via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am prepending an `<option>` via ajax like this:

```
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery('#usp-cat-combo-1').prepend('<option selected="selected" value="'+data.cat_id+'">'+data.cat_name+'</option>');
    }
```

The thing is when I submit the form, that option says not selected and I need to manually select it, even tho I have given the `attribute selected`when I added it

Comment: I tried in snippet and it works maybe something along the line of codes is messing the selected option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting value of the `<select>` instead of setting selected attribute on the option

```
jQuery('#usp-cat-combo-1')
      .prepend('<option value="'+data.cat_id+'">'+data.cat_name+'</option>');
      .val(data.cat_id)
```

Note this assumes the `<select>` is not a `multiple`. If it is a multiple can set `prop('selected',true)` on the new first child

Comment: I tried the OP and it works I think something else is causing the problem

Comment: @guradio was thinking the same to be honest

Comment: You are both right. issue was somewhere else. But this solution works tho

Answer (score -1):

**What you have to do:**

Defined the option which you want to **select** by default like:

```
var selected;
success: function(data) {
  data.cat_id=='1' ? selected = 'selected="selected"' : selected = '';
  jQuery('#usp-cat-combo-1').prepend('<option '+selected+' value="'+data.cat_id+'">'+data.cat_name+'</option>');
}
```

Now it just add **Selected** **Attribute** at one option that you defined not **every option**.

**Note :**

1. Assume that you have data as an **array**.
2. You can use **data.cat_name** or other as you want instead of **cat_id** to defined your **Selected Option**.

**Feel free to comment for more help or other simplification** :)